# Changing position and data of table view on button press

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my app I have a table view, which displays a set of data, and a button. What I want is that, when I click on the button, the table view moves to a new position and also displays a new set of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "i want my table view to move to a new position" you mean you wish to scroll the tableView to a specific place, then use

```
– scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

to scroll the tableView.

If by "i want my table view to move to a new position" you mean you wish to move the tableView to a different location within the superview, then use

```
-setCenter:
```

to set the center to any `CGPoint` you like.

If by "i want my table view to move to a new position" you mean you wish to move the tableView to a different location within the superview and change it's size, then use

```
-setFrame:
```

to set the frame to any `CGRect` you like.

If by "i want my table view to move to a new position" you mean something else entirely, then perhaps you should update your question to be more specific.

To change the data, set the data to an array and simply change the contents of the array.

Comment: i want to change the position with click of a button

Comment: So put this action inside an IBAction that gets called when the button is clicked.

Comment: but this is for scrolling right i want to change the frame of table view

Comment: but i tried changing the frame of the table view and adding new data then reloading the table view but it doewnt helped me

Comment: @Christina, unless you post your code, no one can debug it for you except you.